# Paypal IPN 400 and 403 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal-ipn

Hello people of Stackoverflow, I've been trying to implement IPN functionality to my paypal payments. I'm working on localhost so IPN didn't work. Started using ngrok and now IPN part is working, partially.

```
private class IPNContext
    {
        public HttpRequestBase IPNRequest { get; set; }

        public string RequestBody { get; set; }

        public string Verification { get; set; } 
    }

    [Route("paypalipn")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Receive()
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        IPNContext ipnContext = new IPNContext()
        {
            IPNRequest = Request
        };

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ipnContext.IPNRequest.InputStream, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            ipnContext.RequestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Store the IPN received from 

        LogRequest(ipnContext);

        //Fire and forget verification task
        Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(ipnContext));

        //Reply back a 200 code
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    private void VerifyTask(IPNContext ipnContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var verificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

            //Set values for the verification request
            verificationRequest.Method = "POST";
            verificationRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            //Add cmd=_notify-validate to the payload
            string strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + ipnContext.RequestBody;
            verificationRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

            //verificationRequest.UserAgent = "ASP-IPN-VerificationScript";
            //verificationRequest.KeepAlive = false;

            //Attach payload to the verification request
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                writer.Write(strRequest);
            }

            //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(verificationRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                ipnContext.Verification = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogErr(exception.ToString());

            //Capture exception for manual investigation
        }

        ProcessVerificationResponse(ipnContext);
    }
```

The code above throws 403-Forbidden exception in VerifyTask function. On Paypal IPN documentation, it states and I quote `Please ensure you provide a User-Agent header value that describes your IPN listener, such as, PHP-IPN-VerificationScript.`

If I uncomment line with `verificationRequest.UserAgent = "ASP-IPN-VerificationScript";` then I start getting 400-Bad Request. Anyone had this issue before? I will very much appreciate any help, thanks for reading so far.

For 403-Forbidden:

```
POST https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 1245

cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=10.00&invoice=4967920&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&item_number1=sku&payer_id=UG9FLUCH489QQ&tax=0.00&address_street=asfasdgdsgsd&payment_date=00%3A36%3A22+Jun+28%2C+2021+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=KOI8_R&address_zip=365555&mc_shipping=0.00&first_name=%E1%CC%C5%CB%D3%C1%CE%C4%D2&mc_fee=10.00&address_country_code=RU&address_name=%E4%CF%D3%D4%CF%C5%D7%D3%CB%C9%CA+%E1%CC%C5%CB%D3%C1%CE%C4%D2&notify_version=3.9&custom=latios%3A1000001&payer_status=verified&business=sb-fyb3f6626939%40business.example.com&address_country=Russia&num_cart_items=1&address_city=sggdsgdsgsdgf&verify_sign=As7YjUf-EtwWTklniO1RIaVMU-GLAbAN64Awhlx16OwPRDGAMxNV1f-B&payer_email=sb-mjmkt6611016%40personal.example.com&txn_id=4RF57039YW521103B&payment_type=instant&last_name=%E4%CF%D3%D4%CF%C5%D7%D3%CB%C9%CA&address_state=fhdhfdhfdh&item_name1=TestPayment&receiver_email=sb-fyb3f6626939%40business.example.com&payment_fee=&shipping_discount=0.00&quantity1=1&insurance_amount=0.00&receiver_id=7W727DS9L36YE&txn_type=cart&discount=0.00&mc_gross_1=10.00&mc_currency=RUB&residence_country=RU&test_ipn=1&shipping_method=Default&transaction_subject=Test+Payment&payment_gross=&ipn_track_id=4d1fa1b02fc27
```

I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Content-Length: 419
Server: Varnish
Retry-After: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
Date: Mon, 28 Jun 2021 07:36:31 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Served-By: cache-hhn11549-HHN, cache-ams21035-AMS
X-Cache: MISS, MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
X-Timer: S1624865791.439206,VS0,VE12
Set-Cookie: x-cdn=fastly:AMS; Domain=paypal.com; Path=/; Secure


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Paypal Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Access Denied.</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access "/cgi-bin/webscr" on this server.
<br/>
<p>Reference #16248657919b384e2feca947c115f57
<br/>
<p> Timestamp: 1624865791
</body>
</html>
```

For 400-Bad Request error:

```
POST https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: ASP-IPN-VerificationScript
Host: ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 1245

cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=10.00&invoice=6419605&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&item_number1=sku&payer_id=UG9FLUCH489QQ&tax=0.00&address_street=asfasdgdsgsd&payment_date=00%3A31%3A25+Jun+28%2C+2021+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=KOI8_R&address_zip=365555&mc_shipping=0.00&first_name=%E1%CC%C5%CB%D3%C1%CE%C4%D2&mc_fee=10.00&address_country_code=RU&address_name=%E4%CF%D3%D4%CF%C5%D7%D3%CB%C9%CA+%E1%CC%C5%CB%D3%C1%CE%C4%D2&notify_version=3.9&custom=latios%3A1000001&payer_status=verified&business=sb-fyb3f6626939%40business.example.com&address_country=Russia&num_cart_items=1&address_city=sggdsgdsgsdgf&verify_sign=AX8Qhp1KduwF1PenaWfGM32xmlvMAhGJ2G8kcZxf1Y2LyqJwTyF9J-zn&payer_email=sb-mjmkt6611016%40personal.example.com&txn_id=4H0466721N516441A&payment_type=instant&last_name=%E4%CF%D3%D4%CF%C5%D7%D3%CB%C9%CA&address_state=fhdhfdhfdh&item_name1=TestPayment&receiver_email=sb-fyb3f6626939%40business.example.com&payment_fee=&shipping_discount=0.00&quantity1=1&insurance_amount=0.00&receiver_id=7W727DS9L36YE&txn_type=cart&discount=0.00&mc_gross_1=10.00&mc_currency=RUB&residence_country=RU&test_ipn=1&shipping_method=Default&transaction_subject=Test+Payment&payment_gross=&ipn_track_id=38f99419954c7
```

I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Paypal-Debug-Id: 1dc58fdccb02b
Set-Cookie: Cookie 1
Set-Cookie: Cookie 2
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
Date: Mon, 28 Jun 2021 07:31:39 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Served-By: cache-hhn11528-HHN, cache-ams21054-AMS
X-Cache: MISS, MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
X-Timer: S1624865500.675648,VS0,VE150
Set-Cookie: x-cdn=fastly:AMS; Domain=paypal.com; Path=/; Secure

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

**Solution for people who will find this topic in the future:**

The issue for me was that, both my testing accounts had Cyrillic names. To solve the issue I needed to login to my Business account (account that's going to accept the payment)

- Account Settings
- Website Payments
- Language encoding of payment buttons with PayPal
- Additional features
- Changed the encoding to "UTF-8".

And now it works without an issue.

Comment: Does the response perhaps contain more information about what the problem is?

Comment: @Llama thanks for taking time to check my issue, I'm adding all the additional information I have but it really doesn't return anything specific.

Comment: I've not worked with any PayPal APIs, but I had a look at the sample [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/ht-ipn/) and it seems to be only including key/values where there is a corresponding value (`if (count($keyval) == 2)`). In your example you have `payment_gross=` with no value. If you excldue such cases, does it work?

Comment: @Llama doing a quick Google search gives me information that payment_gross is supposed to be empty for non-USD payments (in my case, my payments are being sent in RUB). I still went through and excluded keys without values, still getting 403-Forbidden & 400-Bad Request respectively.

Comment: Nothing seems obviously wrong vs the example I saw. Hopefully someone with more experience using the PayPal APIs will be able to help you. Sorry I couldn't be more useful.

Comment: @Llama Thank you very much for your attention, friend. I still very much appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same issue with the sandbox API. It was working couple of weeks ago, but now it doesn't (no changes were made at our side) and I get the same errors as Latioss. The live API, however, is working fine (for now). @Latioss, were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @Lanexbg Yes. I already posted solution under the question. It was first layer of the fix for me. After this it started working most of the time, last issue was that I was sending verification multiple times on some occassions. On the other hand, both of my issues were persistent on both sandbox and live. So I can't quite tell solution to your problem if live is working fine but sandbox is not. Could be an issue with sandbox testing accounts, they may have changed something for sandbox etc etc